# __construct() and service.yml in Symfony3

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have some issues with my code, it has separate form, controller and service. Where is the issue here?

form: https://pastebin.com/ERU6hChv 
controller: https://pastebin.com/FMzJ493v 
service:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.form.type.przydzial:
        class: AppBundle\Form\PrzydzialType
        arguments: ['@session']
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

unfortunately i have a warrning:

```
"Warning: Missing argument 1 for AppBundle\Form\PrzydzialType::__construct(), called in G:\Xampp\htdocs\projects\godziny_inz\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry.php on line 85 and defined"
```

Stack Trace:

```
"in src\AppBundle\Form\PrzydzialType.php at line 64"

return 'appbundle_przydzial';
}

public function __construct($session)
{
$this->session = $session; <----------64 line
```

EDIT:

```
if i change this line: 
$form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\PrzydzialType', $przydzial);
to 
$form = $this->createForm('app.form.type.przydzial', $przydzial);
```

I have different warning:

Could not load type "app.form.type.przydzial"

Stack Trace:

in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry.php at line 87

```
if (class_exists($name) && in_array('Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface', class_implements($name))) {
$type = new $name();
} else {
throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Could not load type "%s"', $name)); <---line 87
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Form Type is created with `new` in the FormRegistry instead of using your service. You can find the exact location where this happens in the [FormRegistry](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php#L85). Since you created a service and tagged it as `form.type` I can only assume the problem is somewhere inside the `AppBundle\Form\PrzydzialType` class.

Most likely you either forgot to extend `Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType` or accidentally extended from a wrong one (check your use statements).

Comment: I use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;  in PrzydzialType.php

I checked "php bin/console debug:container" and I haven't form.type.przydzial in cmd.

my service is wrong?

Comment: The service definition looks correct and the location seems right too. Try clearing the cache to force a container rebuild and check again with debug:container to see if you can find the service. Did you maybe accidentally mark the service as private, e.g. do have a line that says `public: false` in the service definition or the new _defaults section?

Comment: Ok, i cleared cache, I tried: php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod, php bin/console cache:clear -e prod and only cache:clear.  Where is public: false in service definiotion? i haven't it.

Comment: If you don't have `public:false` anywhere in your services.yml it's fine. Try calling `$this->get('app.form.type.przydzial');` in your controller. Does that work and return the correct form type? Check the imports in your config.yml for something like `- { resource: services.yml }` to make sure it's actually included

Comment: I have imports: - { resource: services.yml }  in my config file, i add code to my controller, look at this photo : http://imgur.com/a/V9Ows  (sorry i'm beginner)

Comment: Step away from the code for a bit. Maybe have a drink. ;) Then take a look at your services.yml, especially the service name. There must be a typo or something simple like that.

Comment: I changed this line : $form = $this->createForm(PrzydzialType::class, $przydzial);  and i have a new warning : You have requested a non-existent service "app.form.type.przydzial", i cleared cache, I dont know what to do

Comment: i have got the same warning still, and i don't see solution, can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't see the problem. Have you tried creating another service, best something simple without arguments, in your services.yml and fetch that in your controller? That would make it more likely that services.yml isn't imported correctly. You could also try moving the service into config.yml

Comment: Ok. little mistake, i had got two times service, service: {declaration serv}  service: {declaration serv}